# Reading XML in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

I have the following xml from a large xml file.

```
<Text>
   <cp IX='0'/>
   <pp IX='0'/>
   <tp IX='0'/>Wo<cp IX='1'/>rl<cp IX='2'/>d<cp IX='3'/>
   <cp IX='4'/>!!<cp IX='5'/>
</Text>
```

is there any way to access the text in between "cp" and "tp" nodes separately (ex: Wo, rl, d, !!)?
I can get them as a single string but, I need them separately like in an array. Thanks..

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text() method on your XML property:

```
var myXML : XML = <Text>
        <cp IX='0'/>
        <pp IX='0'/>
        <tp IX='0'/>Wo<cp IX='1'/>rl<cp IX='2'/>d<cp IX='3'/>
        <cp IX='4'/>!!<cp IX='5'/>
    </Text>

var text : String = myXML.text().toString();
trace (text); // output World!!
```

Comment: He wants to access text separately.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `Wo` , `rl` , `d` and `!!` are children of `Text` node. Their type is `TEXT_NODE`.

So I would suggest to iterate over all `Text` children, and store those which type is `TEXT_NODE` as elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your `<Text>` tag content as string and use split with regex:

```
var array:Array = textTagContent.split(/<\S*[^>]*>/);
trace(array) // ,,,Wo,rl,d,,!!,
```

Trim it!

```
a = trimArray(a);
```

Use it!

```
trace(a) // Wo,rl,d,!!
```

Trim function:

```
function trimArray(array:Array):Array {
    var a:Array = [];
    for each (var item in array) 
    {
        if (item) {
            a.push(item);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```